# How to use Game Loops to Trigger SignalR Group Messages?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

**Background**

I have built a game on top of SignalR in .NET framework and am now porting to dotnet core. As part of this I have several "Game Rooms" with up to 6 players in each. I am using SignalR's `Group` functionality to support the concept of `GameRoom` - no problems there.

**The Question**

My question, how do I enable each `GameRoom` to broadcast messages automatically every 5 seconds to all members of the group?

I have one `GameHub.cs` which has a `List<GameRoom>`. Each `GameRoom` then maintains all the data (scores, players, SignalR users, SignalR group name, etc) for it's corresponding game. Inside the Game Room I have a Game Loop which I want to leverage to push data to the players. The Game Rooms are static for the duration of the game.

I am unable to ascertain if my dependency modelling is correct in the new dotnet core world.
For example: `GameHub` --> `GameRoom` which in turn contains a simple `Timer` loop. Inside this timer I don't know how to call GameHub to broadcast messages.

In .NET I could leverage `GlobalHost` to get the `GameHub` and broadcast a group message something like this was ok, how does one do something similar for dot-net core implementation? How to use game loops to trigger SignalR group messages?

```
class GameRoom
{
    List<player> _players;
    Scoreboard _scores;
    string _gameRoomName;
    ...
    void GameLoop_Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Game>();
        context.Clients.Group(_gameRoomName).SendMessage(_gameState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Asp.net core, I suggest you could use backgroud service to achieve your requirement. Inside the backrround service you could write the logic to call the hub to send the group message every 5 seconds.

For how to call the ihubcontext, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and this [sample](https://github.com/davidfowl/UT3/blob/fb12e182d42d2a5a902c1979ea0e91b66fe60607/UTT/Scavenger.cs).

For how to use background service, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: So looking at the information above, it appears that the strategy is to have a single background service that runs in the background instantiated upon startup. This background service will then continually poll or check for games that are running and then broadcast the active state of all live games.

Is it just me but doesn't this seem terribly inefficient?

Comment: Thank you for setting me on the right path. I have been successful in adopting a background service that sits well outside my game logic to interrogate GameRooms and broadcast the game state. Whilst I have a solution to the problem - it still feels very silly to keep the background service running all the time even when no games are being played - I will look into streamlining that next. For now thanks for your answer I will mark it as accepted.